# HDRI not being reflected on Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I added a HDRI on cycles, but the image is not appearing on the preview or in the reflection of my material on the model i'm using...
What i'm doing wrong? :/

[image]

Comment: Your glossy shader is WAY to rough, put it at .025, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Nope, still nothing :(

Comment: It looks like you have *Transparent* enabled in *Render settings film*. This will cause the background to be transparent, instead of displaying the HDRi. And your glossy shader is really rough, which will prevent fine details from being visible in reflections (You could try mixing two glossy shaders based on a fresnel node). And you have AO on, which could wash out and make the effect the HDRi less apparent. And it appears you are using a jpg instead of an HDRi, which will make the light from the environment flatter and less apparent, so you may have to increase the *Strength*.

Comment: To be honest i only need the reflection, not the image in the background...yet when i make it appear unchecking Film > Transparent, it only shows me a single color, i think, of the image, it's a Jpg...i added a jpg due to another tutorial.

Comment: Well, now i'm downloading a HDRI, a real one, let's see if this can fix the problem..

Comment: The problem still persist :/

Comment: How about uploading the file to http://pasteall.org/blend/ ?

Comment: It finally worked! i changed the roughness into 0 
lol :D

Comment: Also make sure you're in the right view mode, press num 5 on your keyboard to switch and test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first try using an  *environment*  texture instead of a  *image texture* and then go into the  *Ray Visibility* panel and turn off the channels you don't want the map to show up in.
Next, make sure you have a glossy or reflection shader mixed in to your eyeball material so that it can pick up the environment.

Comment: And roughness should be 0 :)